# Why can't I install grub on /dev/sda3?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, multi-boot

I've installed to hard drive using 50% of HD. So Windows has 2 partitions.

Then I manually made 2 partitions for ubuntu:

```
#3 primary /boot ext4
#5 crypted section with volumegroup for root and swap
```

Then the installation asks me that where to install grub and I write:

```
/dev/sda3
```

And the installation says fatal error. Where do I go wrong? The reason is that I want to create whole drive encrypted HD with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You can't install grub on `/dev/sda3`. Try installing it on `/dev/sda`.

Comment: normally it's perfectly possible to install grub into a partition instead of the mbr, but I don't know if the partition may need a boot-flag.